# HTML 5 <input type"color" /> different on devices

Tags: html, html-input

I'm using the a standard `input` element which renders differently in mobile vs browser

```html
<input type="color" />
```

Browser:

[image]

Mobile:

[image]

Why is this the case? I prefer the Browser version, so if I can force browser rendering for all it would be great

Comment: And you're using the same browser for both mobile and desktop? Also, not sure what you mean by "I prefer the browser version" as you're using a browser in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `<input type="color">` [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color):

> The element's presentation may vary substantially from one browser and/or platform to another—it might be a simple textual input that automatically validates to ensure that the color information is entered in the proper format, or a platform-standard color picker, or some kind of custom color picker window.

Unfortunately there's no way to 'force' a specific presentation.

---

In the ['Appearance variantions'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color#appearance_variations) you'll find some examples on different devices like the macOS system color picker.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this the case?

They use the standard colour picker widget for the platform they run on.

Consistency of UI between applications is a virtue.

> I can force browser rendering

You can't.

The closest you could come would be to implement your own colour picker from scratch or using a library that completely bypasses the native control.

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="color" />`  style depends on the system default styles.
If you want a uniform style try using an external library such as
[Simonwep pickr](https://github.com/Simonwep/pickr)